# Explain answer "COURTESY TITLE" to cryptic clue "Certainly not a rude man."

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

The question is

> **Certainly not a rude man. (8 5)**

The answer is

> **COURTESY TITLE**

I’m relatively new to cryptic crosswords and I can’t figure this one out at all.

Comment: Where is this clue from? e.g. if it's in a newspaper, the name and date of the issue.

Comment: Courtesy is lack of rudeness. It might not be a very *good* clue.

Comment: It’s from a local paper. 
I was expecting an answer relating to man and/or certainly.

Comment: @JaneP please tell us the name and date, still. If we have access to the original puzzle there might be useful context. Additionally, this process credit to the original creator

Comment: It’s the Shrewsbury Chronicle (UK) dated October 12, 2023. No sign of where they get these from.